# Shrinking an image to the coordinates of a mouse click position? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coordinates, css-position

I'm pretty new to this, but I've been fiddling around trying to get an image to shrink to nothing on a central point, which works fairly well using a combination of the below code and relative positioning in the CSS.

```js
$(function() {
            $('#imageID').on('click', function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: 0,
                    height: 0,
                    top: '185px',
                    left: '-2px'
                }, 200);
       
            });
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I'd like to be able to do, however, is to change this so that the image shrinks centred on the point where the click was made. I've had a go at trying out absolute positioning and trying to set the top / left to the values of pageX and pageY (and also with the extra step of assigning them to variables) but no dice.

Does anyone have any idea of how / if this can be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all welcome to Stack Overflow!

### **How about using CSS animations for this?**

Use `transform` instead of `width` and `height` in animations for a better performance.

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#imageID').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass("shrink");
  });
});
```

```css
.shrink {
  animation: shrink 300ms linear forwards;
}
@keyframes shrink {
  to {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imageID" src="http://fillmurray.com/300/300">
```

---

Here's more info on CSS [**transform**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/transform/) and [**animation**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/animation/) properties.

Comment: This looks much better, thanks! Part of the problem is that if I used the old method with anything responsive it wouldn't work properly on smaller images, but this looks like it'll do the trick! Thanks, will look into this!

Comment: Yeah, you can even change the origin of the transformation. The name of the CSS property is pretty straight forward: `transform-origin`. You can change the origin in X and Y axis for 2d and Z axis for 3d as well. The default value is `50% 50% 0`, that's why in the demo you don't need to specify it. Here's another simple [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/7bdm76yf/) to help you better understand what I'm talking about. If you considered this helpful you can mark it as the correct answer. Cheers `:)`

Comment: oh, there's a massive tick... probably be that then ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
            $('#imageID').on('click', function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: 0,
                    height: 0,
                    top: '185px',
                    left: '-2px'
                }, 200);
       
            });
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How is copying the code they tried an answer? Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted.